# how to get difference between two dates angular in months

Tags: angular

I need to Subtract my formControlName - to DateToday and the answer is in Months is that possble?

this my html code:

```
<input style="width:300px" class="form-control" type="date" formControlName="newDepSample" >
```

Comment: Depends on what you think the "*difference in months*" is. What would you expect for instance for  2022-01-31 to 2022-02-01 or 2022-07-01 to 2022-08-31?

Comment: for example. I will set the date picker to (2021-08-27) Subtract to Today'sDate:(2022-09-12).

Comment: That still does not answer the question. What do you expect is the result when you subtract a date from another date?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the date difference by using the [moment js](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  today = moment();

  //here is your formcontrol value
  someDate = moment('2022-01-01 00:00Z');

  diffInMonth = this.today.diff(this.someDate, 'month');
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>

<p>Today: {{ today }}</p>

<p>Some Date: {{ someDate }}</p>
<hr />
<p>Difference in month: {{ diffInMonth }} months</p>
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t1jdr1?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Hi @cfprabhu. I'm having an error on  today = moment(); .even though i added it on my dependencies and import it still error on my end. Can you help me thank you.

Comment: can you post that error msg here?

Comment: If you are going to use a library you may want to consider another one instead of moment.js as its deprecated and the authors themselves recommend not using it as per this post: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: 17 import moment from 'moment';
          ~~~~~~

  node_modules/moment/ts3.1-typings/moment.d.ts:784:1
    784 export = moment;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.

Answer (score 2):

A year is 12 months, so just calculate the diff yourself. No need for a library.

```js
const now = new Date();

function getDiff(dateStr) {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  
  const yearsDiff = now.getFullYear() - date.getFullYear();
  const offset = yearsDiff * 12;
    
  const monthDiff = now.getMonth() - date.getMonth();
  
  const finalDiff = offset + monthDiff;
  
  console.log(finalDiff + ' months ago');
}
```

```html
<input type="date" placeholder="Choose a date" onchange="getDiff(this.value)">
```

Comment: Until OP defines, what in his opionion the "difference in months" really is, answering this question is mere speculation. Your approach returns the same answer(ie `1`)  for both of the following ranges: `2022-01-31 -> 2022-02-01` and `2022-01-01 -> 2022-02-28`, eventhough one is only one day and the other nearly two month. Might be ok, or not. Nobody knows .

Comment: I'm not here to give him the entirety of his code. The idea is here, up to him to use it or not. I'm just giving an alternative to using moment.